# Magento2 Invalid form key. Please refresh the page

Tags: magento2, customer-account, form-key

I am getting the error "Invalid form key. Please Referesh the page" while create the customer account.

Comment: check your console log error

Comment: are you using chrome?

Comment: Yes I am using chrome

Comment: @MohitPatel, I cheked console log error but it show nothing