# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.External Script via Google Tag Manager

Tags: magento2.3

When embedding external scripts with the Google Tag Manager, you always get the message "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page." CSP has inserted all rules and doesn't output errors anymore. We try to test Userlike and Crisp.chat, with both scripts we have the same problem, no errors in the developer console or in the logs. Anybody got any ideas? (Magento 2.3.5-p1)

Comment: I see this error a lot of. I think there is a cookie problem. But I couldn't find a solution. for example; https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316664/magento2-invalid-form-key-please-refresh-the-page